# issue with java 8 collectors Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<String>

Tags: java, java-8, collectors

i was having working code with earlier version of java 8 which i was using to get unique values from list but since i upgraded to JDK 66 its giving me an error

***Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<Object>` to `List<String>`***

```
List<String> instList = new ArrayList<String>();

while (res.next()) {
    instList.add(res.getString("INST").toString());
}           

List<String> instListF = instList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where ***res*** is resultset i am getting from database, not sure what is wrong any idea?

Comment: so the .collect(Collectors.toList()) gives you a List<Object> but you want it to be List<String>

Comment: yes, it was working with JDK 51 but after java upgrade its throwing errors

Comment: `List<String> instListF = instList.stream().map(e->(String) e).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Do you still have compilation error if you remove the `while` loop completely?

Comment: @ Tagir Valeev i cant remove while loops cause i have to fetch data from ResultSet

Comment: @Nomad, of course I understand that the logic of your program will change. We are speaking about compilation error. Will the compilation error disappear or not? I'm not asking you to commit the changed code to production.

Comment: No it does not go after removing while loop

Comment: Is this a `javac` compilation error or is it an error from your IDE? This should work.

Comment: The error is from ide eclipse

Comment: Then upgrade your Eclipse. This works.

Comment: well something is terribly wrong with JDK u66

Comment: @Nomad, no released version of Eclipse reports an error on your example. Are you compiling using Maven or such? In that case the error would probably be raised by javac indeed - which matches your observation that the error was introduced by upgrading the JDK - which then is in conflict with Tagir's answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well I have also faced similar kind of error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Object> to Set<String>` recently. Below is the code snippet-:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[]{"i", "came", "i", "saw", "i", "left"};
    
    Set<String> set = Arrays.asList(arr).stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
    System.out.println(set.size() + "  distinct words: " + set);
}
```

Here is the screen shot for reference-:
[image]

Now let me explain why was I getting this error? In my case code was displaying compile time error because there was mismatch in **compiler version** in project properties. I had selected **1.7** but it should be **1.8** since this feature has been added in **1.8**.

[image]

So please make a note of below points-:

1. Appropriate JDK has been selected in **Java Build Path**. e.g. **JDK 1.8** in this case.
2. Appropriate **compiler version** must be selected under **Java Compiler** (*as displayed in above screenshot*) in project properties. e.g. **1.8**

I hope this would help you.

Answer (score 4):

I checked the following complete example:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test { 
    public List<String> test(ResultSet res) throws SQLException {
        List<String> instList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (res.next()) {
            instList.add(res.getString("INST").toString());
        }           

        List<String> instListF = instList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        return instListF;
    }
}
```

It compiles perfectly with javac 8u25, 8u40, 8u60, 8u71 (note that 8u71 is the security update of 8u66, thus essentially the same). Try to clean your project and rebuild from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

After checking for my compiler level (per Ashish above), 
I realized that I had no datatype on either List or Set. Once I added  it worked.

```
List<Integer> number = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 5, 3);
Set<Integer> square = number.stream()
     .map(x -> x * x)
     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you get this error and for some reason you are stuck with Java <1.8 you can write the following:

```
... .collect(Collectors.<String>toList());
```